# Quickblox How to record call in android?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

quickblox api working fine for calling.I want to record the call so there is any method for recording?

Comment: for mobile devices ?

Comment: yes for  android mobile device , if you have some idea then please share

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

when you receive call you can start recording and on call end you can stop recording. 
for more information go to this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm)

Comment: MediaRecorder can Record Calls ( Not Quickblox WebRtc Calls ) , as all resources like mic , camera are used by Quickblox Sdk so we can not use them so this method can't be use for recording